# Unable to authenticate SMTP via PHP

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

I am unable to send mail from PHP by using PHPMailer. Previously I tried the same via VB.NET and it worked perfectly. While trying, it is throwing me below error -

```
2019-05-13 15:15:46 Connection: opening to smtp-gw.abcd.com:25, timeout=300, options=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ),)
2019-05-13 15:15:46 Connection: opened
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SMTP INBOUND: "220 Mail02.abcd.com ESMTP"
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 Mail02.abcd.com ESMTP
2019-05-13 15:15:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250-Mail02.abcd.com"
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 104857600"
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250 STARTTLS"
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-Mail02.abcd.com250-8BITMIME250-SIZE 104857600250 STARTTLS
2019-05-13 15:15:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SMTP INBOUND: "220 Go ahead with TLS"
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 Go ahead with TLS
2019-05-13 15:15:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250-Mail02.abcd.com"
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250 SIZE 104857600"
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-Mail02.abcd.com250-8BITMIME250 SIZE 104857600
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2019-05-13 15:15:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SMTP INBOUND: "221 Mail02.abcd.com"
2019-05-13 15:15:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 Mail02.abcd.com
2019-05-13 15:15:46 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Here is my code block -

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Load Composer's autoloader
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp-gw.abcd.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'jobnotifier@abcd.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

I am not very sure what I am missing here. I know this SMTP server authentication do not have any password. You can also check the same in .NET code. Here is my code from VB.NET

```
 Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
            Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
            Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("jobnotifier@abcd.com", "")
            Smtp_Server.Port = 25
            Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = False
            Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp-gw.abcd.com"
```

Requesting some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server says it doesn't support authentication either before or after STARTTLS, i.e. `AUTH` does not appear in the list of server capabilities after either of the `EHLO` commands. For example, here's what gmail says:

```
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [88.184.221.3]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

Since your server doesn't seem to allow authentication (and it may that your VB script spots that and doesn't bother trying), tell your script not to use it:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth   = false;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = '';                     // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = '';                               // SMTP password
```

Also, why are you disabling TLS certificate verification? You need to have a *very* good reason for doing that - and not just "to make it work"; if your TLS config is broken, fix it, don't just suppress the errors.

Comment: Hi Synchro, Thanks. I tried these - 1. ENABLED SSL:Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 406] 2. DISABLED SMTPAuth : Its a SUCCESS.. THANK YOU MAN !!!!!!!!

Comment: Read the troubleshooting guide for how to deal with verification failure.